# How to initialise class instance with data belonging to the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a class who's instances are choices from a set of choices. E.g. the instance is a game piece chosen from a set of game pieces.

I thought a good way to go about this is to store the game pieces in the class and when a class instance is initialised, it is set to a certain piece.
The below code doesn't work as I've found out, what's the best way to go about this?

```
class MyClass():
    choices=["foo","bar"]
    def __init__(self,choice):
        self.var=choices[choice]

myinstance=MyClass(0)
print(myinstance.var) #I wan't this to be "foo"
```

Comment: `self.choices[choice]`

Comment: Thank you, I see I completely misunderstood how the class variables work. Coincidentally, is this overall a good way to approach the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is a good way. If you want, you can declare the choices using a class Enum (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can just do:

```
class MyClass():
def __init__(self,choice):
    self.choices=["foo","bar"]
    self.var=self.choices[choice]

myinstance=MyClass(0)
print(myinstance.var) # It should work now
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: how does converting choices from a class to instance var fix his issue? Just adding self.choices and leaving choices in the class def is sufficient, particularly if the class variable isnt going to be mutated in any way thats instance specific

Comment: Well I'm not an expert on python, so I don't have an answer to your question. I'm confused now.